# Can Java load Mac OSX bundles/frameworks/ or dylib? How can it be done?

Tags: java, macos

Can Java load Mac OSX bundles/frameworks/ or dylib? How can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

You could use JNI to call C functions from Java. This C function then can call Objective-C and that can load and call bundles etc. (Note I have not done this so I don't know what exact problems you will find)

Answer (score 0):

There's a java/cocoa bridge that is well documented on apple's dev site. However, this interface is Deprecated. Aside from using that interface, I don't think it's possible.